# Why is silicon used in computer chips?

Tags: elements, semiconductors

Most computer chips contain or are made of silicon. Why silicon? Why not copper or tellurium or some such?

Comment: You should consider asking the exact same question on Physics.SE, a very different answer would come up. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most electron components of computer chips and boards are [semiconductor devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_device) like [transistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor) and [diodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode).
Silicon is, from the [Wikipedia article on semiconductor devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_device):

> By far, silicon (Si) is the most widely used material in semiconductor devices. Its combination of low raw material cost, relatively simple processing, and a useful temperature range make it currently the best compromise among the various competing materials

Silicon is the [second most common element in the earth's crust](http://education.jlab.org/glossary/abund_ele.html) after oxygen, and present in a variety of [silicate minerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicate_minerals).

[Electronics grade silicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon#Electronic_grade) can be produced easily by molten salt electrolysis of these minerals followed by purification by zone refining.

Copper is a conductor, and therefor not suitable for semiconductor devices. Tellurium is [one of the rarest elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tellurium#Occurrence) in the earth's crust.